# Internet Explorer 8 & 7 is converting tabs to spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I'm trying to use javascript with jQuery to convert a tab delimited string to html table.

In the input string rows are separated by `<br/>` and columns by `tabs`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
  $(function(){
    $('div.jstable').each(function(){

      var text = $(this).html();
      var rows = text.split(/<br>/i);
      var htmlString = "<table class='display dataTable'>"
      var startTbody = true;
      for(i = 0; i< rows.length; i++){
        // build header section
        if (i == 0){
          htmlString += '<thead>';
        }else {
          if (startTbody){
            htmlString += '<tbody>';
            startTbody = false;
          }
        }
        htmlString += '<tr>';

        var row = rows[i];
        var columns = row.split('\t'); 
        // build columns
        for (j = 0; j < columns.length; j++ ){
          if (i == 0){
            htmlString += '<th>' + columns[j] + '</th>';
          }else {
            htmlString += '<td>' + columns[j] + '</td>';
          }
        }

        htmlString += '</tr>';
        if (i == 0){
          htmlString += '</thead>'
        } else {
          if (i == rows.length - 1){
            htmlString += '</tbody>'
          }
        }
      }
      htmlString += '</table>';
      $(this).html(htmlString);
    })
  });
```

And here is the input text:

```
  <div class="jstable" style="float: left">
col1    col2    col3<br />asda  fd  dfs<br />mmmm   ffff    ssss
  </div>
```

Unfortunately in IE8/7 the text returned by jquery .html() function has all tabs replaced by spaces.

IE9 is fine, also current versions of Firefox & Chrome work fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW I found out that if I surround the input text with `<pre>` tags the .html() function will return the text with tabs in IE7/8, as expected.

So, the initial example source html will look like this:

```
  <pre class="jstable" style="float: left">
col1    col2    col3<br />asda  fd  dfs<br />mmmm   ffff    ssss
  </pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a regular expression to [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). `/\s+/` will consider consecutive whitespace of any kind as a single delimiter:

```
>>> "one   two".split(/\s+/)
["one", "two"]

>>> "one\ttwo".split(/\s+/)
["one", "two"]

>>> "one\ntwo".split(/\s+/)
["one", "two"]
```

Comment: I thought of this too, but what happens if I have a column with text "John Doe"?

Comment: @Bogdan, in that case you would have to use another regex. I believe `/\t| {2,}/` would achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: that's might work assuming IE is replacing the tab with 2 spaces, not just one. I'll have to double check. I'll get back with more info later. Thanks!

Comment: Just checked. It's just 1 space, unfortunately :(